# double click open another page RadDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik-grid

Hello I recently changed my Datagrid to a RadDatagrid and I have an even OnMouseDoubleClick but Doesn't quite work anymore. If I can get help towards what other changes I have to make to the code inorder for it to work with a RadDataGrid.

```
protected void OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs args)  
{  
    if (sender != null)  
    {  
         var grid = sender as DataGrid;  
         if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count  == 1)  
         {  
             ((ContactsGridViewModel) DataContext).Open<PersonViewModel>();  
         }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: works when i remove the If statement and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only change you'll have to make is on this line:

```
var grid = sender as DataGrid;
```

You're not dealing with a `DataGrid` anymore, so that line will return `null`.

Just cast it to the correct element:

```
var grid = sender as RadGridView;
```

Comment: Makes sense! may i ask which reference are you calling? I dont have RadGridView within that class and just wondering. using Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView Didnt work.